# Am I thinking correct in the proof of $C(a) \subseteq C(a^k)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> **Question:** Let $G$ be a group and $a \in G$. Then for any integer $k$ we have $C(a) \subseteq C(a^k)$.

**My attempt**:
We shall use induction on $k$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ and $k≥0$.
**Base case**: For $k=0$, $C(a^k)=G$ and thus $C(a) \subseteq C(a^k)$ is obvious.
**Inductive case:** Suppose inductively that $C(a) \subseteq C(a^n)$ for some $n ∈ \mathbb Z$ and $n≥0$. We want to show $C(a) \subseteq C(a^{n+1})$. Let $g ∈ G$, we see $a^{n+1}g=aa^ng=aga^n$ by inductive hypothesis. Since $ga^n \in G$ ,thus $aga^n = ga^na= ga^{n+1}$  .This shows $g ∈ C(a^{n+1})$ whenever $g ∈ C(a^n)$ and as $C(a) ⊆ C(a^n)$, thus $Ca(a) \subseteq C(a^{n+1)})$. This closes induction.
Now for the other case when $k$ is negative. Let $y=-k$ , since $y>0$ thus $C(a) \subseteq C(a^y) = C(a^{-k})$. Since $C(a) = C(a^{-1})$ thus we conclude that $C(a) \subseteq C(a^k)$. ∎

**My confusion**:
I think my proof is incorrect. In the line " Since $ga^n \in G$ ,thus $aga^n = ga^na= ga^{n+1}$ " in inductive case , i believe there is mistake. That is i wrote $a() = ()a$ without showing $() ∈ C(a)$.I think the proof can be corrected if i used strong induction.Am I thinking correct? And Is the above proof really correct?

**Edit**: Here $C(a):=\{g ∈ G| ag = ga\}$, called centralizer of $a$ in $G$.

Comment: Induction is not the way to go. If $g\in C(a)$ we have $g^{-1}a^kg=(g^{-1}ag)^k=a^k$.

Comment: The only thing you need to correct in your induction step is to take $g$ in $C(a),$ not just in $G$ or $C(a^n).$ And what this shows is $C(a)\subseteq C(a^{n+1}),$ as wanted.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Oh yeah !! I forgot to use this identity. Thank you.

Comment: @AnneBauval I understood. Thank you , i will correct it in my notes.